# Need a way to save multiple window layouts for multiple configurations of monitors

Tags: macos, mac, applications, display

When I work at my desk, my MBP is connected to two 27" displays, so I have 3 screens, and they're laid out very specifically, so my chat, mail, trello, etc. windows are all in their own spot.

I'm lucky enough to work somewhere that has a [lovely cafe workspace](https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/333949666796371970/photo/1). As such, I like to take my MacBook up there and work on a single task in the morning, which rearranges all my windows to accommodate a single screen, and that's fine.

But when I return to my external displays, I need the ability to make all my windows (at least if they're open) return where they belong. *It only needs to associate an **app** with a location*; I don't need it to remember locations of specific browser windows, etc.

Is there a setting in OSX or an app (I'm willing to pay for it) that will allow me to either associate a layout with a monitor setup, or even just to save multiple layouts that I can snap back to when I switch configurations?

Comment: I asked [the same question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/161375/53464) recently thinking maybe I'd end up implementing this myself. But I've just found an App called [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) that will do this. It's brilliant :-)

Answer (score 4):

There's an application call [Stay](http://cordlessdog.com/stay/) that does this and works very nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for a such tool. This might help us:

http://totalspaces.binaryage.com

It has a way to assign apps to desktops:

[image: It has a way to assign apps to desktops]

I still hope someone would come up with a way to assign application windows to desktops. (Working on multiple Sublime window/projects simultaniously..)